# How to create variables using Powershell in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Trying to do the following in powershell in C#

```
$certThumbrint = "someLocationToACert"
$cert = get-item $certThumbrint

Get-RoleInstanceCount -ServiceName "someServiceName" -DeploymentSlot "someSlot" -RoleName "someRole" -SubscriptionId "someId" -Certificate $cert
```

This works perfectly when running them one by one in the powershell comandline. But I cannot figure out how to do this by code. So far Ive done this.

```
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

pipeline.Commands.Add("$certThumbrint = \"someLocationToACert\"");
pipeline.Commands.Add(@"$cert = get-item $certThumbrint");

Command instanceCount = new Command("Get-RoleInstanceCount");
instanceCount.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ServiceName", "someServiceName"));
....
instanceCount.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Certificate", "$cert"));
```

I then get the following exception:

> "The term '$certThumbrint = "someLocation"' is not recognized as the
>   name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
>   the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again.

I've tried to add the varibles as "AddScrips" and I also used

```
SessionStateVariableEntry var2 = new SessionStateVariableEntry("cert", "get-item $certThumbrint", "Initial session state MyVar1 test");
initialSessionState.Variables.Add(var2);
```

Before creating the runspace. Nothing is working. Also added all the code into a string and tried to run it as a script.

I actually have no way of doing this and it feels like it's a really simple thing that must be able to do... thanks.

Edit: also tried the following:

```
        const string getInstanceCountScript = "$certThumbrint = \"somecert\" \n " + 
                                              "$cert = get-item $certThumbrint \n " +
                                              "Get-RoleInstanceCount -ServiceName someservicename" +
                                                                     ...
                                                                   " -Certificate $cert";

pipeline.Commands.AddScript(getInstanceCountScript);
```

It runs but returns an empty string. If I put the same code into a ps1 file that I call with "Add()" it runs and gives me the right output. But I really dont want to have a load of ps1 files in my project just for 3 lines of code or less.

Answer (score 0):

This code perfectly works for me. Are you shure, that PS1 file contains exact same code?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {


                using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
                {

                    rs.Open();
                    var pipeline = rs.CreatePipeline();
                    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$certThumbrint = \"c:\\1.txt\"\n" +
                                                "$cert = get-item $certThumbrint\n" +
                                                "Get-Content $cert");

                    foreach (var s in pipeline.Invoke())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);

                    }

                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `New-Variable` commandlet.